# Is it OK to use multiple verbs separated by coma that lie between a common subject and object?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs

I am writting a recommendation letter for one of my employees in support of his application for graduate school in Canada and English is not my native language obviously.
Is it grammatically OK just to say:

> "As he knew he was designing a piece of software that
>   stuck other parts together, he patiently listened to, actively answered requests from, and
>   unreservedly provided insights for other developers of our team. "

As you may notice,I put multiple verbs or verb phrases separated by coma between a common subject("He" in this case) and a common object("other developers" in this case)~
Is it grammatically OK to use them in this way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's definitely grammatically correct.  Whether it's good style is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, having a list of verb phrases separated by commas is perfectly grammatical when you are describing several actions someone has done.

(You didn’t ask about this - “stuck other parts together” sounds a bit informal to me for a recommendation letter. Maybe “combined other parts” would sound better- but I don’t know the context (what these are parts of), and since this isn’t the question, feel free to ignore this advice!)

Comment: Thank you so much,Mixolydian! Your answer helps me a lot.The software he developed is middleware software, so the complete sentence is "As he knew he was actually developing a “software glue” that stuck other parts together, he patiently listened to, actively answered requests from, and unreservedly provided insights for other developers of our team. ". The middleware creates communication links for other software modules like a GUI, LTE UE protocol stack modules, and so forth.In this context, which verb is better? "stuck ... together" or "combined" ? Anyway,I appreciate your further advice!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the context. Maybe instead of "a software glue that stuck other parts together," say "software that acted like a glue and facilitated communication between different modules" - if I am understanding what you're saying that his software did. I think it would be good to be specific, as you are in this comment. And it might be a good idea to break this up into a couple of sentences, since it is very long as is: "He knew he was actually developing... . Therefore, he patiently listened..."

Comment: Thanks again.I have revised the recommendation letter according to your advice!